# Transformar imagem em video

Tags: imagem, vídeo, conversão

Bom dia rapaziada, vou começar a desenvolver um app e preciso transformar uma sequência de imagens em um video.
Gostaria de uma dica de como isso pode ser feito, independente de linguagem, framework, etc.
Não tenho a mínima ideia ainda de como desenvolver e com o que desenvolver, estou fazendo algumas pesquisas e gostaria de algumas dicas.

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias bibliotecas para várias linguagens, um que falam que é bom e que existe bastante conteúdo dele no stack é o FFMPEG, para PHP.

Alguns links úteis:

[Uso do FFMPEG de imagem para vídeo em StackOveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268842/how-to-create-videos-from-images-with-php)

[Download da Biblioteca](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)

Comment: Blz, vlw Matheus.

Comment: Magina, mas da uma pesquisada no Stack, tem bastante conteúdo sobre conversão de imagens para vídeos em outras linguagens, aí vai da escolha de cada um, de como prefere trabalhar e de como implantar.